# webpack and webpack internal content in VueJs app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, user-interface, vue-component, vuex

I have a VueJs application and in production mode someone can open debugger mode in the browser and see webpack and webpack-internal's contents,  including the vuejs code

What is the best practice? Should we hide this or is it ok?

If we can hide, how do we do so?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you should take a look vue framework structeres on github.
https://github.com/PanJiaChen/vue-element-admin

Here you can see the structure and best practices.